# Criterion on diagonally similar unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an $n\times n$ invertible complex matrix $A$. If there is a non-singular diagonal complex matrix $D$ so that
$$D^{-1} A D = A^{-*},$$
where $\cdot ^*$ is the complex conjugate transpose, we say $A$ has the property $\mathcal{P}$.

Unitary matrices and all matrices being diagonally similar to a unitary matrix have $\mathcal{P}$. Are there any other matrices with $\mathcal{P}$?

Note: Probably an extra condition on $A$ could be needed to exclude "degenerated cases". Suppose $n>4$, given a $n\times n$ invertible complex matrix $A$ which is irreducible and for every partition of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ into subsets $\alpha,\beta$ with $|\alpha|>2, |\beta|>2$ either rank $A[\alpha|\beta] > 2$ or rank $A[\beta|\alpha] > 2$.